# what are patterns to join two or three time series table's data in bigquery?

Tags: join, time-series, google-bigquery

I'm trying to see if I can join between two or three massively big tables in big query. They are all time series data however with different frequencies. So say for example stream A could have been for sent every 10 seconds and stream B could have been sent every minute. I'm not sure how to join these tables to query them for same time period. There is a business key other than time to join these tables.

I've thought about two options,

- doing an in-memory aggregation before saving data in big query. This might not be too bad, but I think I might have to use a project like apache storm or something but still not very clear. Scaling them manually might be a pain. This will just be a lookup on last known value for each stream before they get persisted in one single bigquery table.
- running queries in parallel against these data streams and then doing the aggregation after you get the result back. This could be very painful if data returned is quite large.

Is there any other way to join these tables in a query itself? I'm new to big query so I'm wondering if I'm missing any tricks.

As an example, say

if stream A is `tstamp:TIMESTAMP, device:STRING, lat:FLOAT, long:FLOAT`
and stream B is `tstamp:TIMESTAMP, device:STRING, status:INTEGER` and data looks something like,

Stream A:

```
tstamp, device, lat, long
2015-02-12 06:13:00, A, 123.22, -1.22
2015-02-12 06:13:00, B, 121.11, -1.56
2015-02-12 06:13:10, A, 123.45, -1.23
2015-02-12 06:13:10, B, 121.11, -1.56
2015-02-12 06:13:20, A, 123.45, -1.26
2015-02-12 06:13:20, B, 121.11, -1.56
2015-02-12 06:13:30, A, 113.45, -1.23
```

Stream B:

```
tstamp, device, status
2015-02-12 06:12:20, A, 1
2015-02-12 06:13:20, A, 0
2015-02-12 06:12:58, B, 1
2015-02-12 06:14:20, A, 1
2015-02-12 06:13:59, B, 1
```

So when you query for 06:13:00 to 06:13:30 for device A, I'd like to see the following data.

```
streamA.tstamp, device, lat, long, status
2015-02-12 06:13:00, A, 123.22, -1.22, 1
2015-02-12 06:13:10, A, 123.45, -1.23, 1
2015-02-12 06:13:20, A, 123.45, -1.26, 0
2015-02-12 06:13:30, A, 113.45, -1.23, 0
```

Mostly if there's no time to join two streams of data then it uses the last known value.

Comment: While what you described is pretty much good, and using Window functions you most likely can do, but can you please post sample data sets and expected query output to guide you better

Comment: @Pentium10 I have updated question with some duff data to explain my question further. Please let me know if you require any further clarification. I'll look at window functions to see what it can do.

Comment: @Pentium 10, I can see LAG function might be what I need to look into but I'm not sure how to use it when joining two tables.

Comment: @Pentium10 Are you happy with the dataset above or do you need any more examples?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure how to join these tables to query them for same time
>   period.

Use modulo to round up/down to the nearest unit you want to use eg: 10 seconds.
Timestamps are stored as unixtimestamp, so you can use something like:

```
res = 1424170343 - (1424170343 % 10)
```

this would round down to the nearest 10 seconds.

Then both tables will be normalized to your unit, hence you can join on the same time + business logic, and use aggregate functions to pick the one you are interested in.

Comment: Can this be done in the query itself or will there be `res` column added to the table separately for each table(stream) and populate it as data is added?